# VBA code for integrating negative exponent

Tags: vba, excel, math, calculus

I am trying to perform an integration using Excel VBA. Was wondering how I would do this using an approximation method if I need to integrate a negative exponent (since x/0 is undefined, hence such approximations could not estimate it)

My current code is:

```
Function Integral(sExp As String, dMin As Double, dMax As Double, lBit As Long)
Dim dU As Double
Dim lU As Long
dU = (dMax - dMin) / lBit
For lU = 1 To lBit
    IntegralTemp = IntegralTemp + Evaluate(Replace(sExp, "u", dMin)) * dU + 0.5 * dU * Abs(Evaluate(Replace(sExp, "u", dMin + dU)) - Evaluate(Replace(sExp, "u", dMin)))
    dMin = dMin + dU
Next lU
Integral = IntegralTemp
End Function
```

Comment: Please provide the integral you try to calculate. And please provide how you are calling your function. Example: `i = Integral("u^-2", 2, 4, 7)`. What do you expect as result? How is the result different from your expectations.

Comment: = Integral("u^(-0.05)", 0, 1, 500). The result is #VALUE.

Comment: You can't evaluate `0^-n` because this is division by zero. But in my opinion `Integral(x^-0.05) dx = x^(-0.05+1)/(-0.05+1) + C = x^0.95/0.95 + C = 100/95*x^0.95 + C`. This integral with lower limit 0 and upper limit 1 = `100/95*1^0.95 - 100/95*0^0.95 ≈ 1,052631579`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a Monte Carlo technique to estimate the value?

Here's a wikipedia article for this approach:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration

Answer (score 0):

I think this is problem with `function Evaluate`.

I try solve this and that has managed to make:

Look on this test function:

```
Function EvaluateTest(str As String)
    EvaluateTest = Evaluate(str)
    EvaluateTest = CStr(EvaluateTest)
End Function
```

`debug.Print EvaluateTest("0^(-0.05)")` show `Error 2007` i think this is dividing by zero -> `0^(-0.05) for VBA is 0/(0^0.05)`

We can catch this error and for thats case accept results = 0

I create function using to catch this 1 error and modified a bit your function. Try this code:

```
Function EvaluateCheck(Exp As String)

Dim EvalCheck As Variant
EvalCheck = Evaluate(Exp)

If VarType(EvalCheck) = vbError Then 'evaluate function error
    Select Case CInt(EvalCheck)
    Case 2007 ' 0/x
    'Debug.Print "Evaluate(" & Exp & ") error= " & CStr(EvalCheck); ""
    EvaluateCheck = 0
    'Case 2015 ' other problems with evaluate (power)
    'Debug.Print "Evaluate(" & Exp & ") error= " & CStr(EvalCheck); ""
    'try use power function not evaluate
    'FindTmp = WorksheetFunction.Find("^", Exp)
        'If FindTmp > 0 Then
        'number_ = CDbl(Mid(Exp, 1, FindTmp - 1))
        'Power_ = Mid(Exp, FindTmp + 1, Len(Exp))
        'Power_ = Replace(Power_, ".", ",") '<- i have problems with CDbl function i must replace . to , maybe you dont need this line
        'Power_ = Replace(Replace(Power_, "(", vbNullString), ")", vbNullString) ' we dont need parentheses
        'PowerDbl = CDbl(Power_)

        'EvaluateCheck = WorksheetFunction.power(number_, PowerDbl)

        'Else
        'Debug.Print "Evaluate(" & Exp & ") error= " & CStr(EvalCheck); " i cant handle that case"
        'End If
    Case Else
    Debug.Print "Evaluate(" & Exp & ") error= " & CStr(EvalCheck); " i cant handle that case"
    End Select
Else ' evaluate no error
EvaluateCheck = EvalCheck
End If

End Function
```

Your function:

```
Function Integral(sExp As String, dMin As Double, dMax As Double, lBit As Long)

Dim dU As Double
Dim lU As Long
Dim eval As Long
Dim EvaluateVal1 As Double 'Evaluate(Replace(sExp, "u", dMin))
Dim EvaluateVal2 As Double 'Evaluate(Replace(sExp, "u", dMin + dU))
Dim sExpTmp As String

dU = (dMax - dMin) / lBit

For lU = 1 To lBit

    'check evaluate
    sExpTmp = Replace(sExp, "u", dMin)
    EvaluateVal1 = EvaluateCheck(sExpTmp)
    sExpTmp = Replace(sExp, "u", dMin + dU)
    EvaluateVal2 = EvaluateCheck(sExpTmp)

    IntegralTemp = IntegralTemp + EvaluateVal1 * dU + 0.5 * dU * Abs(EvaluateVal1 - EvaluateVal2)
    dMin = dMin + dU

Next lU
Integral = IntegralTemp
End Function
```

Some results:

```
debug.print Integral("u^(-0.05)", 0, 1, 500)
 1,05186339856455
debug.print Integral("u^(-0.05)", 0.05, 1, 500)
 0,991802803730478 
debug.print Integral("u^(-0.05)", 0.05, 1.05, 500)
 1,0417624389399
```

Comment: You mentioned: `debug.Print EvaluateTest("0.002^0.05)")` result is `Error 2015`. That's true because there is a closing parenthesis to much. `debug.Print EvaluateTest("0.002^0.05")` = 0.732911438554269

Comment: @AxelRichter: yes, so simple error... `Case 2015` its needless